# Center Navigation bar with logo in the middle

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, center

I would like to have a navigation bar that is fixed at the top and centered horizontally. I would also like to have my logo (ADRENALIZE) centered in the middle of the navigation. Been trying this for a few days and nothing seems to be working.

I have my coding here for you to take a look at. But feel free to directly look at the site, it'll probably help more with the visuals to understand the menu. http://www.adrenalizegaming.com

Currently it is floated to the left... i'm thinking it has something to do with the inline-blocks?

Related HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Meet the teams</a>
<ul class="menu1"><li><a href="../white.php">Adrenalize White</a></li>
<li><a href="../black.php">Adrenalize Black</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="../index.php" id="logo" title="index"><span>index</span></a></li>
<li><a href="../community/"><span class="community">community</span></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

All related CSS:

```
#header img{
max-width:100%;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#header {
z-index: 99;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #000;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
box-shadow:         0px 10px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
}

#header a:link {
font-size: 1.8em;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: coolvetica,helvetica,tahoma;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #1bc7ff;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#menu {
padding:0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu ul{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

#menu li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
background-color: #000;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

#menu ul li {
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;

}

#menu li:hover > ul li {
height: 40px;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li a {
overflow: hidden;
width: 350px;
margin: 0;
border: none;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

Comment: Do you want just the logo centered, or the whole navigation centered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place the menu in the center of the page, just modify your CSS as follows:

```
menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can add `position: fixed;` to to the `#header` in order to keep it fixed at the top when scrolling. Not quite sure, if this is what you want, though.